# 504 When Deploying to Tomcat 7 on Jenkins, But It Is Still Successful

Tags: tomcat, grails, jenkins

I'm using a Jenkins Post Build Task to deploy a Grails app to Tomcat using the Container plugin. After the WAR gets built, this task kicks off and actually deploys just fine. But the task fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/deploy-production/workspace/target/ROOT.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:187)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:64)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:90)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:917)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:890)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:47)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:781)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:753)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:706)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1704)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:230)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 504 for URL: http://10.101.120.1/manager/text/deploy?path=%2F
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:504)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:547)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:273)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:256)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:240)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:107)
    ... 17 more
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 504 for URL: http://10.101.120.1/manager/text/deploy?path=%2F
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:504)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:547)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:273)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:256)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:240)
```

I didn't have much luck with Google trying to find an answer. Any help would be appreciated. I just want the Jenkins build to report as Success instead of Failure. I have some other tasks that depend on this succeeding.

Comment: Looks like here discussed the similar theme `http://www.coderanch.com/t/361183/Servlets/java/Server-returned-HTTP-response-code`. Problem solved by fixing `Codebase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to adjust the `worker.worker1.reply_timeout` for mod_jk.